# How to set a semi-positive Parameter(matrix) in CVXPY?

Tags: python, cvxpy

I want to use warm start to check whether there's performance benefit by setting a cvx.Parameter, while I come accross this:

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules.
```

My code is here:

```
import time 
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx


m = 300
x = cvx.Variable((m, 1))
p_cov = cvx.Parameter((m, m))
prob = cvx.Problem(cvx.Maximize(-cvx.quad_form(x, p_cov)), [x>=0, cvx.sum(x)==1])

for _ in range(10):
    df_return = np.random.randn(m, m+1)
    cov = np.cov(df_return)
    p_cov.value = cov
    t1 = time.time()
    prob.solve(warm_start=True)
    t2 = time.time()
    print("Solve time:", round(t2-t1, 2))
```

I think the point is that p_cov should be a semi-positive matrix, but I just can't solve it. Look forward your help, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right! You just need to tell cvxpy that `p_cov` is positive semidefinite.

```
p_cov = cvx.Parameter((m, m), PSD=True)
```

DCP can now compute the correct nature of this expression:

```
cvx.quad_form(x, p_cov)
```

Which is:

```
Expression(CONVEX, NONNEGATIVE, (1, 1))
```

Instead of:

```
Expression(UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, (1, 1))
```

Find more documentation in [Advanced Features](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/advanced/index.html#attributes).